# getting google adwords to send the utm_term parameter

Tags: google-ads, utm-parameters

When I click on a Bing ad for my website the URL that it takes me to has mscklid, utm_source, utm_term and other utm_* parameters that are tacked onto the URL.

How can I get Google ads to behave similarly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the utm parameters in `Settings -> Account settings -> Tracking` by making use of the below tracking template

`{lpurl}?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&campaignid={campaignid}&keyword={keyword}`

[image]

The variables like lpurl, campaignid, and keyword are autofilled by Google Ads, [docs on same](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10070427?hl=en). Once this is done, you can test the Ad by going to `Edit Ad -> Ad URL options -> Test`.

Note: [Google doesn't provide you the search term](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61685071/3524733) value but only the keyword it was matched for. You can alternatively connect Google Ads account to Google Analytics to view search term in aggregates, but sending the utm parameters are good to have for universal analytics outside of GA.